# x axis tick labels are one position ahead of data points

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, seaborn, xticks

I have a seaborn lineplot that shows two categories' quarterly count changes. The issue is that the x-axis labels are one position ahead of the data points. I adjusted my code, but it didn't help.

Create example data

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

categories = ['A', 'B']
quarters = []
for year in range(2014, 2024):
    for quarter in range(1, 5):
        quarters.append(f"{year}-Q{quarter}")
data = []
for category in categories:
    for quarter in quarters:
        count = random.randint(40000, 500000)
        data.append({'category': category, 'quarter': quarter, 'count': count})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Create the chart

```
# Create the lineplot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = sns.lineplot(x="quarter", y="count", hue="category", data=df, marker="o")
plt.xlabel("Quarter")
plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

# Set the x-axis tick positions and labels based on the quarters in the DataFrame
x_positions = range(len(quarters))
ax.set_xticks(x_positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(quarters, rotation=45)  # Display every label

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The chart
[image]

Comment: if you make rotation = 90, you will see that the data is correctly labeled. With a rotation=45, it will show the labels in this fashion. I dont think you have an issue with the plot

Comment: Specifically: you might think that the upper-right corner of each label would be beneath the tick it corresponds to, but it isn't. The *center* of each label is. The labels happen to be about two ticks wide, which makes it extra misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be happier with the results you get using

```
ax.set_xticklabels(quarters, rotation=45, fontdict={'horizontalalignment': 'right'})
```

Which looks like this:

[image: plot with rotated labels and right alignment]

In my opinion it pushes the labels a little *too* far left, though. The result with `rotation=90` is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a problem with the data. Your label is rotated to 45 degrees and to accommodate that, it shows a bit off.

Here's the code and image with rotation=90

```
# Set the x-axis tick positions and labels based on the quarters in the DataFrame
x_positions = range(len(quarters))
ax.set_xticks(x_positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(quarters, rotation=90)  # Display every label
```

[image]